# Tool tip in gui not displaying?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am using the .setToolTipText component so that the text "This will show up when you hover over it" shows up when the mouse is hovered over the window. Currently, everything else is working, except for the tooltip. Right now the tool tip only displays when hovered above the words, how do I make it display whenever I hover over the window itself? This is the code:

Here is the main class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class evenmoregui{
public static void main (String[ ] args){

    moregui guiobject = new moregui();
    guiobject.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Makes the program terminate when the x is clicked
    guiobject.setSize(275,180); //This is the size
    guiobject.setVisible(true); //Means it should show up, actually puts the window on screen
}


}
```

Here is the class with the actual .setToolTip part:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout; //Make it so the windows don't overlap, it just formats the windows properly
import javax.swing.JFrame;  //Gives you all the windows features in the window, like minimize 
import javax.swing.JLabel;  //Allows text and simple images on window

public class moregui extends JFrame { //JFrame gives you all the basic windows features.
private JLabel item1;

public moregui(){ //Constructor
    super("This is the title bar"); //These are all imported methods


    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //Gives default layout


    item1 = new JLabel("This is a sentence"); //Text on the screen


    item1.setToolTipText("This will show up when you hover over it");


    add(item1); //Adds item1 into window
                  }


                                 }
```

Comment: The code you posted works for me.

Comment: Is there any way for the tool tip to display when hovering over the window itself, right now it only displays after hovering over the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a correct code. Try hovering over it longer.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setToolTipText("ToolTIp");
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel lblLabel = new JLabel("Label");
        panel.add(lblLabel);
```

Let me know if you ran into any more problems.

Comment: Is there any way for the tool tip to display when hovering over the window itself, right now it only displays after hovering over the words.

Comment: There sure is. Just add a  special panel, and add the label to it. Then make the tooltip for the panel.  Ill modify my answer for you to show you an example

Answer (score 2):

Try adding getRootPane().setToolTipText("String");
this will make sure that the tool tip is shown when hovered over JFrame

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;    
import javax.swing.JFrame; window, like minimize 
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
public class moregui extends JFrame{ 
private JLabel item1;
public moregui(){                 //Constructor
super("This is the title bar"); //These are all imported methods
getRootPane().setToolTipText("Hovering over window");
setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //Gives default layout
item1 = new JLabel("This is a sentence"); //Text on the screen
item1.setToolTipText("This will show up when you hover over it");
add(item1); //Adds item1 into window
}
}
```